# Uncaught TypeError: Object(...) is not a function in the browser

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, imageloader

I'm trying to use Ionic Image Loader for Image Loading and caching. There is no error at the time of compiling but in the browser, it shows the following error. I'm pasting details from my package.json file. I'm new to ionic and angular. Please let me know how to fix this issue.

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object(...) is not a function  at index.js:1193 
at Module../node_modules/@ionic-native/file/index.js (index.js:1370) 
at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:84) at Module../node_modules/ionic-image-loader/dist/image-loader.module.js (image-loader.module.js:1)    
at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:84) at Module../node_modules/ionic-image-loader/dist/index.js (index.js:1) at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:84)  
at Module../src/app/app-routing.module.ts (main.js:494) 
at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:84) 
at Module../src/app/app.module.ts (app.component.ts:12)
```

My package.json looks like below

```
    {
  "name": "blank",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "author": "Ionic Framework",
  "homepage": "https://ionicframework.com/",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "~8.1.2",
    "@angular/core": "~8.1.2",
    "@angular/forms": "~8.1.2",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~8.1.2",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~8.1.2",
    "@angular/router": "~8.1.2",
    "@ionic-native/core": "^5.0.0-beta.14",
    "@ionic-native/file": "^4.20.0",
    "@ionic-native/file-transfer": "^5.20.0",
    "@ionic-native/splash-screen": "^5.0.0",
    "@ionic-native/status-bar": "^5.0.0",
    "@ionic/angular": "^4.7.1",
    "cordova-plugin-file": "6.0.2",
    "core-js": "^2.5.4",
    "ionic-image-loader": "^6.3.3",
    "rxjs": "^6.5.4",
    "tslib": "^1.9.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.9.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/architect": "~0.801.2",
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.801.2",
    "@angular-devkit/core": "~8.1.2",
    "@angular-devkit/schematics": "~8.1.2",
    "@angular/cli": "~8.1.2",
    "@angular/compiler": "~8.1.2",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~8.1.2",
    "@angular/language-service": "~8.1.2",
    "@ionic/angular-toolkit": "^2.1.1",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.3.8",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/node": "~8.9.4",
    "codelyzer": "^5.0.0",
    "jasmine-core": "^3.5.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~4.1.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.4.0",
    "protractor": "~5.4.0",
    "ts-node": "~7.0.0",
    "tslint": "~5.15.0",
    "typescript": "~3.4.3"
  },
  "description": "An Ionic project",
  "cordova": {
    "plugins": {
      "cordova-plugin-file": {}
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Most likely a version mismatch between `@ionic-native/core` and `@ionic-native/file`.

Comment: I changed the version of @ionic-native/file to 5.0.0. Now error changed to Uncaught Error: Can't resolve all parameters for ImageLoader: ([object Object], ?, [object Object], [object Object]). at syntaxError (compiler.js:2175) at CompileMetadataResolver._getDependenciesMetadata (compiler.js:20166) at CompileMetadataResolver._getTypeMetadata (compiler.js:20061)

Comment: Deleted the node_module and ran npm install but it didn't work either.

Comment: Updated the versions "@ionic-native/core": "^5.0.0",
    "@ionic-native/file": "^5.0.0"

Comment: Then `npm i ionic-image-loader@beta` should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is most likely because of a version mismatch.

The current version of `ionic-image-loader` [does not yet support v5](https://github.com/zyra/ionic-image-loader/blob/master/package.json#L43) of `@ionic-native/file` but there is [a beta version available](https://github.com/zyra/ionic-image-loader/issues/275) which [does support it](https://github.com/zyra/ionic-image-loader/blob/v4/package.json#L24).

Make sure that all `@ionic-native/*` packages are on the same major version. Use v5 if you want to use the beta version, otherwise use v5 and the latest stable version of `ionic-image-loader`.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It was a version mismatch. It worked when I used the beta version.

Comment: You're welcome. And please don't forget to [mark the answer as accepted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).